# Problem with comparing the input with the file info

Tags: python, file, text

I'm trying to make a login pass thing but despite all the efforts it just doesn't work. Spent 2 hours looking for a solution and have literally rewritten this program bout 5 times. need your help guys. And yes I'm aware of the fh.seek(0) spam being dummy but im still a newbie at this

I need it to compare my input login and pass to the ones that are in the text file and if they are similar to write "Access granted". If not - Access denied.

The problem is that it keeps saying that they are different even though I have made the program write both input and text file info together to compare them. They were similar. I tried messing with backspaces because my program for some reason kept adding backspace to my input so I added backspaces to text files yet it was still incorrect.

```
a = input('Login - ')
b = input('Pass - ')
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\text.txt', 'r') as fh:
    login = (fh.readlines()[0])
    print(login, a)
    fh.seek(0)
    passw = (fh.readlines()[1])
    print(passw, b)
    fh.seek(0)
    if (a == login) and (b == passw):
        fh.seek(0)
        print(fh.readlines()[2])
    else:
        fh.seek(0)
        print(fh.readlines()[3])
```

---

the text file itself (without dots ofc, i just dont know how to make lists here without em):

- bloopbloop@gmail.com
- asdasd
- Access granted.
- Access denied.

Comment: You've edited what you want it to do, but what is it actually doing? And instead of using `seek` and `readlines` constantly, you should just save the return of `readlines` into a variables and use that variable multiple times.

Comment: @Carcigenicate isn't it exactly what I'm doing? I've saved readlines into login and passw.

Comment: I mean do `lines = fh.readlines()`, then `login = lines[0]` and `passw = lines[1]`. That'll be much quicker, and you won't need to call `seek` over and over since you're only reading from the file once. That won't solve your problem, but it's far more proper.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thas was actually a great advice thanks, made the code look much nicer. Yet the problem is still present, for some reason it still says that input and info from the text file are different.

Comment: Why are you using seek? What does the data even look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines` keeps the terminating newline of each line. You can see this if you print out the result of `readlines`:

```
lines = fh.readlines()
print(lines)

['bloopbloop@gmail.com\n', 'asdasd\n', 'Access granted.\n', 'Access denied.']
```

Note the `"\n"`s. Unless the user also enters those, the two won't match.

You could just remove them by using string [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
if a == login.rstrip("\n") and b == passw.rstrip("\n"):
    . . .
```

When in doubt, **print out the data to verify what you're working with**.

---

On top of that though, I'm going to make further suggestions:

- You're calling `readlines` over and over which is necessitating the `seek` calls, and will be slower than necessary.
- Plus as a consequence of the first, you're keeping the file open longer than you need to.

I'd change it to:

```
a = input('Login - ')
b = input('Pass - ')

with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\text.txt', 'r') as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

# File gets closed before this is reached
login = lines[0]
passw = lines[1]

if a == login.rstrip("\n") and b == passw.rstrip("\n"):
    print(lines[2])
else:
    print(lines[3])
```

Or, using unpacking on `lines`, you can get rid of the messy `lines[0]` parts:

```
a = input('Login - ')
b = input('Pass - ')

with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\text.txt', 'r') as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

# Unpack lines into multiple variables
valid_user, valid_pass, granted_msg, error_msg = lines  

if a == valid_user.rstrip("\n") and b == valid_pass.rstrip("\n"):
    print(granted_msg)
else:
    print(error_msg)
```